# float-left not working in relative position

Tags: css, next.js, css-position, tailwind-css

I am trying to place my Image on the left side of the div.
Anything I try to do to move the Image or the div fail to work. Why is the Image stuck in the center?

I was able to achieve this using flexbox but had to switch to relative positioning because of the Nextjs Image component conflict. In the Image tag you'll see "layout='fill'" which was the root of my problem, but I am unable to rid myself of that piece of code

```html
<div className="relative w-full bg-blue p-4 my-4 rounded-2xl lg:basis-5/12">
    <Image className="float-left mr-4" src={"/"+icon} layout={"fill"} objectFit={"contain"} />
    <div>
        <h3>{ title }</h3>
        <p>
            { paragraph }
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I am getting right now:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `float` will not work with `layout='fill'`. Change it to either 'fixed' or 'intrinsic'. I recommend wrapping the `Image` tag into a `div` and making the div float. Try something like this.

```
<div className="bg-blue relative my-4 w-full rounded-2xl p-4 lg:basis-5/12">
      <div className="float-left mr-4">
        <Image src={'/' + icon} layout={'fixed'} height="120" width="120" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>{title}</h3>
        <p>{paragraph}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And to improvise it. You do not even need to use float. You can achieve same with flex. So if using `float` is not important you can do something like this

```
<div className="bg-blue my-4 flex w-full gap-4 rounded-2xl p-4 lg:basis-5/12">
      <Image src={'/' + icon} layout={'intrinsic'} height="120" width="120" alt="" />
      <div>
        <h3>{title}</h3>
        <p>{paragraph}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```